# Android - Running a delayed action after activity is destroyed?

Tags: android, delay, lifecycle

I am trying to do some cleanup after an activity is destroyed.
The thing is, this should happen with a short period of delay after the activity is destroyed.
Is it possible to do something like this in onDestroy()?

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mPresenter.performDelayedCleanup();
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

I know the activity will be alive for at least 100ms because the message queue has a reference to the activity object during that delay(please correct me if this is wrong), but after performing the cleanup, it will be freed so I don't think this will cause major memory leak. I know this is kinda nasty but is there any possibility of danger?

Thanks

Comment: So did you solve the problem?